# Could this imaginary cooling solution work?

Tags: thermodynamics, heat-engine, cooling, heat-conduction, thermoelectricity

Imagine a perfectly insulated ideal closed cylinder. Inside, at the two ends there are two bodies, one with the temperature of T the other with temperature -T. Between the almost touching bodies with temperature difference we place a thermoelectric generator, that uses heat flux for electricity generation. If heat energy moves towards the colder object through the thermoelectric panel and assume it converts some percent of it to electrical energy, will the system cool down by that much? Will temperature go down in the chamber with equal amount to the electricity produced? (Assume we use up the electricity generated by the TEG and we actually do some work with lets say 99.999% efficiency.)

Comment: Are you measuring temperature in Kelvin scale, where $0$ means absolute $0$? If so, a negative temperature isn't possible in ordinary circumstances. Certain spin systems can have negative temperatures, but it doesn't sound like that is what you are talking about.

Comment: No, only not negative Kelvin temperatures considered. (Celsius-scale)